# Is there a way to specify Entity for a Doctrine event listener?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I was reading: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

It appears that using Doctrine event listeners this way is a bit wasteful, because I can not just define a specific entity to listen to and have to check for entity's class within a listener class. This seems like a waste. Is there a way to indicate specific Entity to listen to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need to include this logic at the top of your listener. This is typically an `instanceof` check:

```
public function prePersist($eventArgs)
{
    // i.e. using the MongoDB ODM
    $doc = $eventArgs->getDocument();
    if (!$doc instanceof MyModel) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it's a waste, doesn't it? For it to be called on each and every entity when I only need it for one.

Comment: Adding this logic upstream would just add complexity for no real performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Since Doctrine 2.4 you can use [Entity listeners](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners), they are called only for specific entity type.